# How to mongoose model based on dynamic schema passed as parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am new on mongoose and for expressjs

I want to retrieve a collection based on the doc and model. 
I have multiple schema that inherits a common schema.

```
const extendSchema = (schema: mongoose.Schema<any>, definition: any): Schema<any> => {
  return new mongoose.Schema({ ...schema.obj, ...definition, ...{ strict: false }});
};

const CommonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... });

const OtherSchema = extendSchema(CommonSchema, { ... });

const OtherOtherSchema = extendSchema(CommonSchema, { ... });
```

Then, I want to retrieve the collection from the mongoose

```
const getCollectionObject = (collection: string, schema: Schema) => {
  return collection.model(collection, schema);
};


// get the first collection
export const getOtherCollection = async (name: string, id: string) => {
  try {
    const model = getCollectionObject(name, OtherSchema);
    const document = await model.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)).lean();
    return document;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};


// get the second collection
export const getOtherOtherCollection = async (name: string, id: string) => {
  try {
    const model = getCollectionObject(name, OtherOtherSchema);
    const document = await model.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)).lean();
    return document;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

I've got an error below
[image]

Is it possible?
Thank you in advance!

PS: I've already saw other posts which the solution is to make the properties optional.

Comment: Check [discriminators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) if it fits to your case.

Comment: Hi @SuleymanSah Thank you. Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my issue.

Create a common schema plus the other schema

```
const CommonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... });
const OtherSchema = { ... };
const OtherOtherSchema = { ... };
```

Then, I declared my based model.

```
const Base = mongoose.model('collection-name', CommonSchema);
```

Next, I created my other models based on the base model using discriminator

```
const OtherModel = Base.discriminator("Other", new mongoose.Schema(OtherSchema));
const OtherOtherModel = Base.discriminator("OtherOther", new mongoose.Schema(OtherOtherSchema));
```

You can now use the model on any scoped function, you may export it if you want to.

```
Other.create({ ... });
Other.findById()

OtherOther.create();
OtherOther.findById();
```

please let me know if this right approach
or you have any other suggestions

Thanks!